# Grails 2.4.3, upgrade params, request

Tags: json, grails, parameters

Upgrade from Grails 2.2.2 to Grails 2.4.3

we are attempting to test everything and our search which is done through a rest call, is receiving its search parameters on the request.JSON in 2.4.3.  In 2.2.2 it used to be on the params object.

When did this change?
Why did this change?

The calling application has not changed how it is doing the calling. But, when we are upgrading, I am looking for the documentation on what else has changed in this area to make sure I cover it all.

The only thing I found is related to this: but it not very specific. http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/introduction.html#whatsNew23

Old way

```
SearchDataTableCommand lSearchCommand = new SearchDataTableCommand()
bindData( lSearchCommand, params, [exclude: ['beforeDate', 'afterDate' ] ] )

// Need to set the date range manually to get to the correct type.
lSearchCommand.afterDay = params.date( 'afterDay', 'MM/dd/yyyy' )
lSearchCommand.beforeDay = params.date( 'beforeDay', 'MM/dd/yyyy' )
```

New way

```
bindData( lSearchCommand, request.JSON, [exclude: ['beforeDate', 'afterDate' ] ] )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were major [changes to databinding in Grails 2.3](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/guide/upgradingFromPreviousVersionsOfGrails.html). If you want to revert to the old behaviour, try adding:

```
grails.databinding.useSpringBinder = true
```

to `grails-app/conf/Config.groovy`. AFAIK, the best way to see all the changes from versions A and B of Grails is to go through the release notes for each version between the two. The easiest way to find them is via the "Select a major version" dropdown on the [downloads page](https://grails.org/download).

Comment: Any details on what the "major" changes were and how they differ from the previous implementation as far as behavior is concerned?

Comment: @JoshuaMoore the changes are *mostly* backwardly compatible. I don't have enough bandwidth in the comments to describe the behavioural differences between the old and new binder. For that level of detail, ask a question and post the URL here.